Organizing the labels with ggrepel
I want to label the deferentially expressed genes in a volcano plot. I have tried playing around with the parameters in the geom_label_repel function but the labels turn out to be messy.
Is there any way I can organize them, especially have the blue labels stick to the left side and vice versa?

resLFC <- read.delim("resLFC f2 vs f1 chronic.txt")
ggplot(data= resLFC, aes(x= log2FoldChange, y= -log10(padj), col=diffs, label=delabel))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-20,20), ylim= c(0,80))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-1, 1), col="blue", linetype="dashed")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 4, col= "red", linetype="dashed") +
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("dodgerblue1", "gray", "deeppink1"),
                     labels = c("Downregulated", "Not significant", "Upregulated"))+
  labs(color = "x",
       x= expression("log"[2]*"FC"), y= expression("-log"[10]*"p-value"))+
  geom_label_repel(nudge_x = c(-10,10), nudge_y = c(0,20),force=10, max.iter=20000, max.segment.length = 0.01, max.overlaps = 1000)+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.88, 0.88))


You can try splitting the data into two groups based on your "x" variable (downregulated vs upregulated) and then call the geom_label_repel function twice, once for each group, fiddling with the "nudge_x" argument.
Example using the mtcars dataset where I split on the median wt:
library(ggplot2)

cars1 <- filter(mtcars, wt<median(wt))
cars2 <- filter(mtcars, wt>=median(wt))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = median(mtcars$wt), col="blue", linetype="dashed") +
  geom_label_repel(data=cars1, nudge_x = -1, label=rownames(cars1)) +
  geom_label_repel(data=cars2, nudge_x = +1, label=rownames(cars2)) 


